# JIRA SM. Не работает поиск на русском языке в базе знаний

Tags: search, jira, sd, confluence

Подскажите, долго мучаюсь с проблей что в Jira Service Management связанной с Confluence не работает поиск статей на русском языке. Ни в портале самообслуживания, ни в внутри проекта. Находил темы где это уже исправили, но в своей версии я этого не заметил.
При поиске на русском получаю такой результат:

```
{"errors":[{"errorMessage":"Не удалось отправить запрос на сервер базы знаний."}],"reasonKey":"sd.knowledge.base.applink.request.failure","reasonCode":"503"}
```

Мой конфиг:
Jira SM 9.9.1,
Tomcat 9.0.73

В самом Confluence поиск на русском работает, а в Service Management нет.

Кто лечил это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлено.

В файле `server.xml` необходимо изменить параметр `useBodyEncodingForURI` на `true`.